Japanese word for stew?
In the sense of the meal consisting of boiled vegetables and meat, what Japanese word would describe this ?
Tangentially, are there any broadly applicable grammatical rules that would help me describe a variety of, mostly traditionally English, dishes ?
For example, would it sound natural to say:
"ゆでるやさいとにくをたべた" ( I ate boiled vegetables and meat )
Or would this raise the question, "don't you mean you had a stew ?"
I am reasonably beginner to Japanese so any help is appreciated.
Apologies on the lack of Kanji above, I am not sure how to type Kanji on my current keyboard.

When you say you want a Japanese word, do you mean not a loanword, like シチュー?

If one exists, yes. I would guess there may be a Japanese equivalent to a stew, but possibly not something like a Sunday roast.

As for vocabulary:

煮込み【にこみ】 is the word closest to the English "stew". It broadly refers to stewed dishes where meat, seafood, and vegetables are cooked slowly in a thick sauce. For example, "lamb stew" can be translated as ラム肉の煮込み.
シチュー is a common word loaned from the English "stew", but in Japanese, this refers specifically to cream stew (クリームシチュー) or beef stew (ビーフシチュー). Other types of stew are usually not called a シチュー.

As for grammar:
茹でる【ゆでる】野菜【やさい】 means "vegetable to boil" (or "vegetable that boils something" in a rare context) rather than "boiled vegetable". The simplest way to say "boiled vegetable" is 茹でた野菜, using the ta-form. You can read this question for the underlying grammar: What are the general principles of using verbs to modify nouns (e.g. 焦げるトースト/焦げたトースト)?
